# How can I save a git "rebase in progress"?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm in the middle of a large "rebase in progress" with numerous *conflicts*.

I would like to set this progress aside and attempt to resolve this issue using another approach.

Is there a way I can save an *in-progress* rebase such that I can finish it later?

Comment: I would do the following. Stash the changes, create a new branch out of it, like branch 2 and then stash apply the changes so that you can work on that branch. On the initial branch I would do the other approach.

Comment: @AndreiT: unfortunately, you can't stash a conflicted merge (because each stash is just a clump of commits, and you can't commit while conflicted).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're sitting at a conflicted merge as part of a rebase, you are kind of stuck.  Here is why, how, and what you *can* do.

#### Rebase = repeated cherry-pick

Fundamentally, a rebase operation in Git is just a series of cherry-pick operations.  We start with something like this:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \
           B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

and we want to end up with:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \           \
           \           B1'-B2'-B3'  <-- branchB
            \
             B1--B2--B3   [abandoned]
```

The way we (or Git) achieve this is by using `git cherry-pick`, or something equivalent, to *copy* existing commit `B1` (turning it into a patch and applying it) to come just after `A5`, and copy `B2` to come after `B1'`, and so on.

Interactive rebase literally runs `git cherry-pick` for each "pick" operation you leave in the instructions.  Non-interactive rebase has several options, including running `git cherry-pick`.

When cherry-picking a commit, if there are conflicts while applying it, Git can use a three-way merge.  This can still fail with a conflict.  This stops the rebase.  Or, when using interactive rebase, you can choose to "edit" a commit, in which case Git cherry-picks that commit and then stops the rebase.  In either case, Git leaves behind enough information for you to have Git resume the rebase later.

#### Conflicts are in the index

As a quick reminder, let's note that Git's *index* is where you build the *next* commit.  Normally there is one entry for each file to be committed, so that if your next commit will consist of just three files named `README`, `file`, and `otherfile`, there will be three index entries.

Note that the index is separate from the *work tree*, which contains files in normal, non-Gitty format.  You can edit these files, compile them, use them to serve web pages, and so on, unlike the internal Git format for index and repository files.  (The work-tree can also hold untracked files, not that this matters during rebase.)

During a conflicted merge, each index entry exposes its individual *slots*.  There are up to four slots per entry, and they are numbered.  Slot zero holds the normal, unconflicted file (if that exists), otherwise it's empty.  Slots 1-3, if in use, hold the three conflicting parts that must be resolved.<sup>1</sup>  These are the *base* version (from the *merge base*), the "local" or `--ours` version, and the other or `--theirs` or sometimes "remote" version respectively.  Your job is to edit the work-tree version of the file, resolve the conflicts, and then `git add` the result.  This copies the adjusted work-tree version into slot zero in the index, wiping out the slot 1-3 entries.  Now the file is resolved and ready to commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hence, *either* slot 0 is occupied and 1-3 are empty, or else slot 0 is empty and slots 1-3 are occupied.  There are some oddball cases where slot 1, 2, and/or 3 can also be empty, e.g., if you get a modify/delete conflict or an add/add conflict, but usually it's "0 empty means 1-3 are full" and vice versa.

---

#### But there's only one index

The very phrase *the* index implies that there is only one.  This is mostly true.

Because the unmerged state is in this ("the") index, and there is only *one* index, anything else that needs to use *the* index cannot proceed until you finish resolving the conflicts (and then make a commit).

You can, if you like, simply `git add` the un-fixed/un-resolved items and `git commit` the result, just to get the conflicts out of the way.  The drawback here is that Git won't retain which files were conflicted: you will wipe out the slot 1-3 entries and Git will think you are all done.

You could *save* the index—it's an ordinary file; you can copy it out of `.git/index` somewhere else.  But because it's a binary file with various kinds of special internal use—the index is also called the "cache" and it caches internal file system data for speed—this is not really very safe.  (It would be nice if Git had a way to "export" the index state, and then "import" it again later, so that you really *could* save and restore merge conflict states.  But Git doesn't.)

So, for safety if nothing else, it's advisable to finish resolving this conflicted merge state.  Or, if you have not *started* resolving, just don't even start: then there's no work to save.

#### Where you are now

Let's say you started that "branch B" rebase I drew above, and are currently stuck in the middle of copying commit `B2`, with some conflicts unresolved.  Here's what you actually have right now:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \           \
           \           B1'  <-- HEAD
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

with the index in conflicted state.  You also have a "detached HEAD": Git is building the new chain of commits this way.  The name `HEAD` points to all completed commits.

If you have done some resolving work, you should finish it up (since it's too hard to save unresolved state) or at least make note of what's unresolved (since you can add files to your next commit) and then run `git commit` to create commit `B2'`:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \           \
           \           B1'-B2'  <-- HEAD
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

If you have not done any resolving work, there's no actual work to save, so don't run `git commit`.  But *either way*, **now** it's time to create a branch or tag name, pointing to the same commit that `HEAD` now points to:

```
$ git branch saveme    # or git tag saveme
```

Now you have this:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \           \
           \           B1'-B2'  <-- HEAD, saveme
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- branchB
```

Now you can just:

```
$ git rebase --abort
```

which makes Git stop the rebase attempt and move back to `branchB`:

```
...--A1--A2--A3--A4--A5   <-- branchA
          \           \
           \           B1'-B2'  <-- saveme
            \
             B1--B2--B3   <-- HEAD->branchB
```

Now you have saved all the work you have done so far, and can go back and retry the rebase later.  You have the resolution you (or Git) made for `B1'`, and if you made commit `B2'`, you have the resolution you made for that as well.  These are commits `saveme~1` and `saveme`, respectively; or just commit `saveme`, if there is only the one commit.

Comment: In the four slots you describe I can see where the version from the merge base comes from, and both 'ours' and 'theirs' seem obvious. But what is the "normal unconflicted file", where is that from?

Comment: @dumbledad: The first unconflicted version ever, came from you (or some other human, presumably). If there is a conflict, slot 0 is unoccupied: there isn't an unconflicted version. It's now up to *you* to resolve the conflict (using the work-tree version and/or the three slot-1-2-3 versions), then run `git add` on whatever you came up with, writing that to slot 0 as the normal unconflicted version. That then goes into the next commit, so whatever is in each commit is also unconflicted by definition. **Ah, I see the wording problem, will fix.**

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer.

Comment: I usually zone out on long Git answers due to them generally being full of nonsense flex terms intended to show how smart the author is.  This was really good, though, embellished in just the right places to add vital context without the nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with an approach that works, but a bit of a hack:

Re-clone the repo into a different directory, leaving the *rebase-in-progress* as-is.

Comment: This does indeed work: it gets you a clone with its own index and work-tree, and the index and work-tree in the new clone are independent of the index and work-tree of the in-progress rebase. Another very handy trick (available since Git 2.5 but I don't trust it much before 2.6) is `git worktree add`, which makes a new work-tree with its own separate index. However, there's a limitation: each added work-tree must be on *its own* branch. The in-progress rebase is on *no* branch (detached HEAD) but once you finish the rebase, it will try to go back to its original branch, so be careful here.

Comment: But for giant repositories this may take too much space.

Comment: @dumbledad I amost cannot imagine a repo so big that you cannot have 2 copies on disk at a time. Mayyybe I could see it if the repo had a lot of large media files. At that point, maybe its time to re-consider version-controlling those along side the code.

Answer (score 2):

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687681/5506730) mentioned, rebase is just a series of cherry-picks. If you are in a middle of a conflicting rebase (means some cherry-picks already happened) and you have to abort it, execute `git rebase --abort`.

Later you can hit `git reflog` which is kind of a history of the past git events. This will show you a list where you will see the abort event and all the previous `cherry-pick` events one-by-one.

Every event belongs a hash. You can now jump to that last step before the abort by `git reset --hard <hash-from-reflog-list>`.
You wont'be in rebasing mode of course, but you can now continue the rebasing with normal cherry-picks.

Be aware! This will roll back all your other git changes as well what you have done after the abortion.