# Is it possible to git stash an interactive rebase in progress?

Tags: git, interactive, git-rebase, git-stash, git-workflow

I am currently rebasing origin/master onto a branch that was created from origin/master a while ago and the developer that worked on the branch is not available right now.

I have resolved some conflicts on the first commits of the feature branch but come to a point where I must wait for the developer to know how to finalize the rebase.

Is there a way to keep the conflict resolution I already did (~30 minutes) so that I can move on to another task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that `git stash` does is make a commit.  (Well, two commits, but that doesn't matter just at this point.  The commits `git stash` makes are on *no* branch, and are structured oddly, but the key is that it makes commits.  That's because commits are the way to save files in Git.  Even Git's `git notes` are commits!  Like stashes, they are not on branches, but they do save files, so they are commits.)

If you can make a commit with `git stash`, you can make a commit with `git commit`.

If not—if you have not completed the resolution of the merge conflicts—you are basically stuck.  You *must* resolve all the conflicts before you can commit.  See [How can I save a git "rebase in progress"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41685791/1256452) for (much) more about this.

Note that if you have a new enough Git to have `git worktree add`, you can set up multiple work-trees, each on a different branch.  Each work-tree gets *its own index* (see that other question and answer for why this is important), so it's possible to leave an in-progress rebase with merge conflicts in "the" index and switch to another branch in another work-tree and do ordinary work.  In other words, "the" index is now a per-work-tree index, so the fact that the merge conflicts are in "the" index "locks up" that one work-tree, but not any others.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!That gives me clues on what is happening under the hood. I would not have imagined this question would lead me to a rabbit hole...

Answer (score 1):

Another brain-dead simple solution is to simply copy the entire folder containing the git repository, mid-rebase. This should always work. May be a good idea to delete that folder when done (rebased and pushed).

Answer (score 0):

In future, you can use rerere, which will record your resolutions. This won't instantly get you back to 30 minutes into the rebase, but it should help a lot, basically you just confirm your resolutions up to the point where you stopped. I don't know why rerere doesn't come as standard with Git, it's so useful.

Comment: In the future you could edit the answer and concentrate all ideas into single answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or another idea is to commit and make a branch mid-rebase, then git cherry-pick remaining the un-rebased commits onto it later.